# Python3 OCR script returns "illegal instruction Core Dumped"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr

I am developing an OCR script, it works fine on my laptop, but when I try to run it on my Synology NAS it does nothing but I get an error

> Illegal instruction - core dumped

However if I run it on NAS using python 2.7 it returns me syntax error, so in 2.7 its working (if I could solve dependencies, but some libraries are just for 3.x)

Can somebody give me a solution, I tried everything I could.

This is my code:

```
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import pillow
import os

def common_elements(list_1, list_2):
    a_set = set(list_1)
    b_set = set(list_2)
    if (a_set & b_set):
        umplutura=1
    else:
        
        for iterio in intrari:
            img1 = np.array(Image.open(iterio))
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img1)
            file_no_ext = iterio.replace('.png', '.txt')
            file_no_ext2 = file_no_ext.replace('.jpg','.txt')
            f = open("/home/adminq/Work/Conta/file_manager/Documente Ocr-izate/Contracte/"+file_no_ext2, "w")
            print(text, file=f)

    
    

#Lista ce contine numele fisierelor din directoriul de Upload cu extensie
intrari = []
#Lista ce contine numele fisierelor din directoriul de Upload fara extensie
intrari2=[]
#Lista ce contine numele fisierelor din directoriul de Output fara extensie
iesiri=[]
output_dir = r"/home/adminq/Work/Conta/file_manager/Documente Ocr-izate/Contracte"
directory = r"/home/adminq/Work/Conta/file_manager/Contracte"
for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    intrari.append(entry.name)

print(intrari)

for intra_acasa in intrari:
    nume2 = intra_acasa
    intrare_no_ext = nume2.replace('.png', '')
    intrare_no_ext2 = intrare_no_ext.replace('.jpg', '')
    intrari2.append(intrare_no_ext2)

print(intrari2)

for iesi_acasa in os.scandir(output_dir):
    nume = iesi_acasa.name
    iesire_no_ext = nume.replace('.txt', '')
    iesiri.append(iesire_no_ext)
    
print(iesiri)   

print(common_elements(intrari2,iesiri))
```